# SVG: Color (fill) a rectangle by hovering another rectangle

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, fill

I need your help!

I want to be able to hover the left part of my SVG-graphics (the lightgrey part). While hovering, I want the rectangle with the *id="margin-bottom"* to be filled red.

Link to my problem: http://cssdeck.com/labs/sjhr6oat

Why am I incapable of doing this? It can't be that difficult. Thanks for your help everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. You need to group both elements inside a common `<g>` element. Hovering over an element can only have an effect on the element itself and child elements.
2. You could use JavaScript
3. You could use SMIL

## CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
  #group:hover #to_be_colored_rect {
    fill:red
  }
  /* If you don't want that the color changes when
     hovering over to_be_colored_rect, then use this: */
  #to_be_colored_rect {
    pointer-events:none;
  }
</style>
<g id="group">
  <rect width="20" height="20"/>
  <rect id="to_be_colored_rect" width="20" height="20" y="20"/>
</g>
```

## JavaScript

Quick and dirty:

```
<rect width="20" height="20" 
  onmousemove="document.getElementById('to_be_colored_rect').setAttribute('fill','red')"
  onmouseout="document.getElementById('to_be_colored_rect').removeAttribute('fill')"/>
<rect id="to_be_colored_rect" width="20" height="20" y="20"/>
```

(Please move `mousemove`/`mouseout` event handling to separate script for production, this just demonstrates the basic principle.)

## SMIL

```
<rect width="20" height="20" id="sensitive_rect"/>
<rect width="20" height="20" y="20">
  <set attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" to="red"
    begin="sensitive_rect.mousemove" end="sensitive_rect.mouseout"/>
</rect>
```

This is IMO a very elegant solution, but unfortunately, SMIL is not very consistently supported.

Comment: Thank you all! I got it .. you were all really helpful! Thanks ;D

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could just simply change the fill property of the first rectangle when you hover over the second rectangle.

HTML

```
<rect onmouseover="turnred()" onmouseout="turnwhite()" id="margin_left"  width="40" height="420"/> // Replace line 7 with this line
```

Javascript

```
function turnred() {
   document.getElementById("margin_bottom").style.fill="red";
}

function turnwhite() {
   document.getElementById("margin_bottom").style.fill="white";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working page: http://cssdeck.com/labs/4r8hitea
Basically it's the same code as World Bright's using jQuery

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.